# TortoiseSVN failing to commit

Tags: tortoisesvn

I've been using TortoiseSVN for a while and recently came back to recommitting all my changes and came across an error I've been so-far unable to solve.  The only thing about my working folder C:\Development\myproject is that I've added a lot of folders/files since my last commit.  What's the best course of action?  Also I started an update, however that overwrote some my files, before I paniced and stop it before too much damage was done.

[image: TortoiseSVN error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `Clean Up` command on the directory, then `Update` and finally `Commit`.

If that doesn't work, the error is moaning about deleting a directory with child items. If you know which the folder is, you can delete it by opening it in `Repro Browser` and delete it through that. After that, `Update` and `Commit` again and hopefully it should work. That always solves this error for me.